# Axios response undefined when function does not find user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

Im trying to access error message from express server with redux toolkit. If there is no user found then we send error message with status code.Everything is ok when i use postman, i get error response. But when im trying to access this on Client side, axios response is undefined when i get error.In network tab i stil get error. That leads to redux toolkit reducer not rejecting and me not able to get an error message.

Server controller and service function

```
controller
....

try {
         
          const user = await findUser({
            ...some values
          });

          //I want this message in redux error message

           if (!user) return res.status(404).send('No user found!') 
          
          const response = await friendService.sendInvitation({...some values});
           
          res.send(response);
        } catch (error) {
          res.status(400).send(error);
        }
...
const findUser=async({id,username})=>{
  
   const user= await users.findOne(...some logic)
   
   
    return user
  }
```

findUser is returning user if found, if not then its undefined.
When i use axios and look for non existing user i get response undefined.But i cant get any error from backend.

**Edit**
findUser is returning null if user is not found 
Redux toolkit slice with call to an api

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://localhost:4000/api',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type':"application/json"
    },
    withCredentials:true
})

....

 const sendInvitation = createAsyncThunk("friends/sendInvitation", async({ username, shortId }, thunkApi) => {
      try {
        if (!username || !shortId) return;
        const response = await api.post(`/friend/send`, { username, shortId })
          return response;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
```

Comment: please show us your frontend code where you call axios

Comment: Did you try `console.log(error.response)`

Comment: I dont get to error because reducer is fulfilled. I could rejectWithValue in try block, forcing  error message, but i want to access message from server  and not write new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sendInvitation = createAsyncThunk("friends/sendInvitation", async({ username, shortId }, thunkApi) => {
      try {
        if (!username || !shortId) return;
        const {data} = await api.post(`/friend/send`, { username, shortId })
          return data;
      } catch (error) {
        const message =
  (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString();
return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
      }
```

With your extraReducer,

```
   .addCase(sendInvitation.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
```

So when the request fails, you send a message in the state, which is achieved from the rejection call

I assume you have an initial state like this

```
const initialState = {
  data: null,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};

if (!user) return res.status(404).send({message:'No user found!'})
```

Comment: Ive got similar initialState and extraReducer, but i cant access data from response because it is undefined.So im not able to rejectWithValue because the message will be 'cant read "data" etc etc.

Comment: I have added an edit please reffer to it. Am sure it will work

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesnt solve an issue. I think problem is with axios response being undefined after not finding anything.